# File deletes without explicitly telling Java to delete

Tags: java

offending code:

```
    public JWave(String s){
      this.f = new File(s);
      try{
         /**if(!this.f.exists()){
            this.f.createNewFile();
         }*/
         this.datafis = new FileInputStream(f);
         this.datafos = new FileOutputStream(f);
         //datafis.skip(44);
      }catch(IOException e){
         System.out.println(e.toString());
      }
      //generateAttributes();
   }
```

and test file:

```
public class testFile{
       public static void main(String[] args){
          JWave j = new JWave("harm.wav");
          //System.out.println(j.getAttributes());
          j.close();
       }
    }
```

also github repo: https://github.com/Donald-Tho/JWave
harm.wav is a working wav file, 600 KB before, 0 KB after.

To make it clear, when I call the Constructor, then close the streams after, it deletes the file, even though I haven't told it to explicitly. The desired behaviour is for it to keep the file intact.

I have the test file, wav file, and JWave file all in the github repo for easy access.

Comment: Do you close the streams anywhere?

Comment: Desired behaviour is for the file to not be deleted. I have given you the problem, error, and code necessary to reproduce the problem. Since you need it, I have added the wave file to the repo....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you open a file for output, that tells the operating system to *immediately* truncate the file to zero bytes long.

To make it clear to people who don't know the difference ... *this is not the same as deleting the file*.

The only way to not truncate the file is to open it in "append" mode.  But that means that new data will be written the end of the file, which is probably not the right thing to do with a ".wav" file.

If you don't want the file to be truncated immediately, and append mode is wrong, only open the file when you are ready to start writing data to it.

If you want to replace a complete file with another complete file, then you need to 1) write the new data as a temporary file in the same directory, and then 2) rename the new file in place of the old one.

Comment: thank you, I suppose I could write to a temp file, then in the close method I interleave the new data with the old, creating a third file. What might be best is to save the data in the class then create a new file from scratch.